# Hide mailchimp checkbox?

Tags: plugin-mailchimpsubscribe

I'm using solspace's freeform with the mailchimp mailing list plugin. All is working OK except I don't want to see the checkbox on the form. Can this be hidden with with an 'override' in the form tag?

Comment: Are you using this plugin?  https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft

Comment: Yes. And that's working great. I was just trying to switch over my form code to use Freeform for all my forms and couldn't see a way to hide the checkbox their code creates on the front end.

Comment: Right sorry, never used Freeform.

Comment: I set it to checked automatically, and just hid it with CSS